# Mysql Query Optimization, Remove a 'NOT IN (SELECT CLAUSE)' using joins

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables, called login_log, logs the timestamp of each email that logs into a website.  The other table is called admin and contains administration rights.  Both have the email as a unique identifier.

I want to get a list of all emails that have not logged-in in the past 90 days.  The problem is the login_log table simply logs every email that logs in with the timestamp, it doesn't store a most recent log in just a list of times where the user logged in.  So I can easily get a list of the users to keep and using the 'NOT' keyword those I don't want to keep.  But it runs really slow using the 'NOT IN' syntax.  So the below statement has a sub-query that grabs all emails in the last 90 days that I want to keep, and the outer grabs all the email I don't want.

```
SELECT distinct a.email FROM admin a WHERE a.email NOT IN (
    SELECT distinct a.email FROM admin a 
    INNER JOIN login_log ll ON a.email = ll.email AND 
    (ll.timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 7776000)  /* 90 days in seconds */
);
```

So my question is what would be a good method of changing this into a JOIN or some other optimized query?

Comment: Is a.email an indexed column? Does anything prevent you from simply adding a last_login table somewhere?

Comment: Can the `admin` table contain multiple rows with the same email address? (I noticed you used DISTINCT above).

Comment: @Femi Yes it potentially could.  There are multiple sites using the same tables (using a field merchant_id to differentiate),  the login_log table is not site specific, but would still have duplicate emails, since every login is recorded.

Comment: @linuxbochs The admin table is indexed, the login_log is not, so I imagine throwing in an index would increase the speed quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return all emails without login in the last 90 days:

```
select distinct a.email, last_login
from admin a 
inner join (
    select email, max(timestamp) as last_login
    from login_log
    group by email
    ) ll
on a.email = ll.email
where last_login < unix_timestamp() - 7776000
```

An index on login_log.email would speed it up.

EDIT:

This could be faster:

```
select distinct a.email
from admin a 
left outer join (
    select email
    from login_log
    where timestamp >= unix_timestamp() - 7776000
    ) ll
on a.email = ll.email
where ll.timestamp is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using HAVING:

```
SELECT distinct a.email FROM admin a
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT distinct a.email FROM admin a
     INNER JOIN login_log ll ON a.email = ll.email 
       AND (ll.timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 7776000)
    ) as tmp ON tmp.email = admin.email
HAVING tmp.email IS NULL;
```

Although this still has a sub-select, it is only calculated once, instead of once per record in admin. It should improve performance significantly.

Comment: This is a nice solution but I keep getting syntax errors stating Unknown column.